# How to copy lot of entries in MongoDB with slight modifications (Java driver)?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

Imagine I have a MongoDB collection with following fields:

1. `buildingID` (String)
2. `projectID` (String)
3. `coords` (array of longitude/latitude coordinates)

I have lots of records, which are assigned - via the `projectID` property - to project A. Now I want to

1. take all records belonging to project A,
2. duplicate them such that
3. in the new records, all fields except `projectID` are equal to the original ones and
4. `projectID` is equal to project B.

I could do it like this:

```
Collection coll = getDb().getCollection("MyColl");

final Map<String,Object> query = new HashMap<>();
query.put("projectid", "projectA");

DBCursor cursor = coll.find(new BasicDBObject(query));

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    final BasicDBObject curRecord = cursor.next();

    final BasicDBObject newRecord = clone(curRecord);
    newRecord.set("projectid", "projectB");
    coll.insert(newRecord);
}
```

`clone` creates a copy of `curRecord`?

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Can I avoid getting data out of MongoDB into Java and back into MongoDB?

Comment: I think you might want to do this on the server using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is a more elegant way to do it. Use the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/), as this will reduce the number of writes and responses to the server considerably:

```
    BulkWriteOperation bulk = coll.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();
    Integer count = 0;

    DBCursor cursor = coll.find(new BasicDBObject("projectid", "projectA"));

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject curRecord = cursor.next();
        curRecord.removeField("_id");  // why bother with a clone when you can remove the _id
        curRecord.put("projectid","projectB"); // replace the projectid
        bulk.insert(curRecord);
        count++;

        if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
            bulk.execute();
            bulk = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();
        }
    }

    if (count % 1000 != 0 )
        bulk.execute();
```

Now things are only sent/recieved from the server every 1000 operations. This is also an internal limit, but it helps to limit memory consumption to manage this yourself.